# Audio problems with RGS and LDAP

Tags: remote-access, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have been working on creating a new RHEL 6.x image for a college computer lab.  We use LDAP authentication so that the users can freely move between computers, and so that they can then connect to high-powered machines to create CAD drawings.  I was working on getting this working under RHEL 6.3 (6.4 isn't supported by RGS 6.0). I have tried changing permissions, and adding the audio group to the LDAP group, and vice a versa.   Has anyone successfully implemented a Red Hat (family) system with RGS 6.0 with functioning audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it, I updated the kernel (not as part of the fix for this problem, but just to patch the security flaw in the older Linux kernels) and I manually compiled the Audio driver in conjunction with the new kernel and it worked.

My guess, (and it really is just a guess, but its a guess about a good solution)  is that there was a part of the old audio driver that wasn't getting deleted from the kernel modules, and thus when I would install the new audio stuff, the old module wouldn't be compatible with the new information, and thus the audio stopped working.

I hope that this might be helpful to someone else later on.